# Decimated parts falling into each other

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I created a plane, subdivided and decimated it. After that I edge split the plane to create multiple triangle. To give them a 3rd dimension solidify was used. 
When I now want to animate the triangles falling down on a rigid plane, everything works fine so far except that the triangles fall into each other. Is there a way to prevent this? I played around with self collision but nothing I did helped. Do you have any tips?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a single object, you have to enable *Self Collision* to allow parts of itself to collide with itself.

[image: self collision setting]

However, you will need a lot of accuracy and samples. The situation of many rigid pieces would be better suited with a **Rigid Body** Simulation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you elaborate accuracy and samples? Where do I find these settings? I just started using blender and some settings are confusing. What is actually doing the physics simulation? Is it the render engine?


If I used rigid body simulation I would need to seperate the plane in to parts. Is there a quick way to apply rigid body to all these parts in one go?